# Smoothie chart with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, smoothie.js

This is probably pretty obvious but I am trying to put a smoothie chart inside of a bootstrap `col`. The chart doesn't expand to fill the column and I'm simply getting a small chart with lots of extra space.

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <canvas id="mycanvas" width="100%" height="300px"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var smoothie = new SmoothieChart({millisPerPixel:25,grid:{millisPerLine:3000,verticalSections:8},timestampFormatter:SmoothieChart.timeFormatter, tooltip: true});
smoothie.streamTo(document.getElementById("mycanvas"), 0);
```

[image: This is the output]

I want the chart to fill the rest of the column space, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me creating a class as **canvasheight** and then defining height in Style tag worked

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <canvas id="mycanvas" class="canvaswidth" height="300px"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.canvaswidth{
   width:100% !important;
}
</style>
```